# Declaring custom failure action for warden not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, warden

Current in my warden manager we have a custom failure app declared.

```
    Rails.configuration.middleware.use Warden::Manager do |manager|
      manager.default_strategies :password
      manager.failure_app = lambda { |env| SessionsController.action(:new).call(env) }
    end
```

However, for one of my strategies I want to use a different failure action so I tried declaring a custom action in the failure as such:

```
 def authenticate!
   email =  params["email"] || params['session']['email']
   pw =  params["password"] || params['session']['password']
   user = User.find_by_email email
   if user && user.authenticate_and_activated(pw)
     success! user
   else
     throw(:warden, :stuff => "foo", :action => :failure)   
   end
 end
```

and even in my controller action:

```
 def sign_in
   @user = warden.authenticate! :action => :failure
   ...
 end
```

and here is my failure action:

```
def failure        
  warden.custom_failure!
  render :json => {:success => false, :errors => ["Login Failed"]}
 end
```

But the issue is that it seems to be ignoring it and only calling the action declared in my manager. Anyone have an idea of what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure out my solution with an idea suggested by JonRowe on the Warden issues on Github(https://github.com/hassox/warden/issues/73)

With his suggestion of altering my lambda, I was able to change my warden manager configuration to be:

```
Rails.configuration.middleware.use Warden::Manager do |manager|
  manager.default_strategies :password
  manager.failure_app = lambda { |env| 
    failure_action = env["warden.options"][:action].to_sym
    SessionsController.action(failure_action).call(env) 
  }
end
```

This picked up the failure action I was passing into it. It seems it is stored in the "warden.options" hash under action.

Comment: I was able to replace the hardcoded "SessionsController" with a reference to the controller being used.  This might make this solution a little more flexible if you have multiple sessions controllers.

`env["action_controller.instance"].class.action(failure_action).call(env)`